# Make Django's ModelChoiceField display as a dropdown with title and image

Tags: python, django, html-select, forms, modelchoicefield

Below is my Django form. I would like to display a thumbnail and title together in a **dropdown** element, not as a radio button. With this configuration, it makes my form element a radio button.

What am I doing wrong, I cannot figure this out. If I change **widget=forms.Select()**, it creates a dropdown with only the title, but does not display the thumbnail beside the title.

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe("<img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150'><p>"+str(obj.category)+"</p>")

countries_list = ImageModel.objects.all()

class SubCatForm(forms.Form):
    category_pic = CustomChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), queryset=countries_list, empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = SubCatModel
        fields = ("sub_category_name", "category", "category_pic")
        widgets = {
            'sub_category_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'span11'})
        }
```

Comment: A simple `<select>` element is not capable of rendering `<img>` elements. This is not a Django issue. To accomplish this, you will need to find a 3rd party package that is able to handle this (select2 comes to mind, https://select2.github.io). Also, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/